# How to read file contents in batches using java code

Tags: java, file

I am very much new to java programming.I need to read a huge java file in smaller chunks. For example
if I have the file as follows

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

I have the batch size as 2. As per the above file I need to create 4 batches and then process. I dont need to have a multi threading mode in this task.
Following is what I have tried. I know it is simple and I have come closer to what i want to acheive.
Any suggestions on the code will be helpful

```
public class testing {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("This is for testing");
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Files.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int batchSize=2;
    int batchCount=0;
    int lineIncr=0;
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    int nextBatch=0;
    int i=0;
    while((line=bfr.readLine())!= null) {
        if (lineIncr <=nextBatch ) {
            System.out.println(line);
            int b=0;
            i=i+1;
            if (i==2) {
                b=b+1;
                System.out.println("batchSize : "+b);
System.out.println("batchSize : "+b);
            }
        }

    }   
    bfr.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
final int batchSize = 2;
Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Files.txt");

try (BufferedReader bfr = Files.newBufferedReader(file)) {
    List<String> batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
    for (String line; (line = bfr.readLine()) != null; ) {
        batch.add(line);
        if (batch.size() == batchSize) {
            process(batch);
            batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize); // or: batch.clear()
        }
    }
    if (! batch.isEmpty()) {
        process(batch);
    }
}
```

Notable features:

- Uses new [NIO 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) `Path` API, instead of old `File` API.
- Uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure `Reader` is always closed correctly.
- Collects the batch of lines in a `List<String>`.
- Calls `process(List<String> batch)` method to do the processing.
- Call `process()` with partial batch, if last batch is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I will be processing more than 4 million lines of a file. Will there be any performance impact. Am just trying to understand..because I might need to give 10000 as my batch size. Just wanted to know. Also how do i resume from a line if there are any issues or how do i skip lines in case of issue..say read from 10001 line onwards

Comment: Add `if (linesToSkip > 0) { linesToSkip--; } else { ... }` inside the `for` loop.